# group rows with equal data in one column and summing its related data in another column [ORACLE SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

ORACLE SQL

i have a table CUSTOMER_UNITS

```
CUSTOMER_ID    UNITS_SOLD
AAAA    350
BBBB    150
CCCC    650
DDDD    250
AAAA    950
BBBB    450
CCCC    450
DDDD    350
```

i need to write a query that will SUM(UNITS_SOLD) per CUSTOMER_ID, WHERE UNITS_SOLD >= 350 and give me a total. so basically the results should be:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    UNITS_SOLD
AAAA    1300
BBBB    450
CCCC    1100
DDDD    350
```

I tired the following code:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID
   ,SUM(UNITS_SOLD)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID, UNITS_SOLD FROM CUSTOMER_UNITS)
WHERE UNITS_SOLD >= 350
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

but it returns an error; ORA-00904: "UNITS_SOLD": invalid identifier

i'm sorry for asking this i know it must be super simple but i've tried at least 15 suggestions with no luck..

Comment: I don't know why you are using that subquery, but anyway, you just need to give an alias to it: `FROM (SELECT DIS......) AS T`

Answer (score 0):

this is for select the valuue with more of 350 using having ..

```
select CUSTOMER_ID,  sum(UNITS_SOLD) 
from CUSTOMER_UNITS
group by CUSTOMER_ID
having sum(UNITS_SOLD) >= 350 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what i was thinking.. The following returned what i wanted:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID
   ,SUM(UNITS_SOLD)
FROM
    CUSTOMER_UNITS
WHERE
    UNITS_SOLD >= 350
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Thanks for the suggestions. I guess sometimes you go the difficult way when it's actually really simple